# A series of a function: comparison test?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Consider $\sum a_nx^n$.

I wish to determine a convergence radius, but the $a_n$s do not behave nicely so root and ratio tests didn't get me anywhere.

I can bound them from above and from below. Is the method to determine convergence then to use some sort of comparison test to show (absolute) convergence? That is, abs$(mx^n) \le $ abs($a_nx^n$) $\le $ abs($Mx^n$) where $m$and $M$are constants, and these power series converge if and only if $|x| < 1$? Would this work?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not tell us what the $a_n$ are?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $m,M>0$, s.t. $m < |a_n| < M$, then $\sum a_nx^n$ converges if and only if $|x|<1$

If $x<1$, by comparison test the series converge because $|a_nx^n|\leq M|x|^n$.

If $|x|\geq 1$ then $|a_nx^n| \geq m|x|^n \geq m$, so the series diverges because the summands do not converge to $0$.